# Redshift Permissions Revoke Grant

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

How do i restrict a user from granting permissions to object he owns?

```
create schema sandbox;
grant usage on schema sandbox to developer;
grant create on schema sandbox to developer;

grant select on all tables in schema sandbox to developer;
grant insert on all tables in schema sandbox to developer;
grant update on all tables in schema sandbox to developer;
grant delete on all tables in schema sandbox to developer;
```

But how do we prevent the developer from performing 
    grant select on table table to developer_2;